# How to create a dictionary assigning values from a list and generate the same key for each one

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list and I'd like that each item of the list becomes the value of a key that doesn't exist yet but should be created.

This is the list:

```
['King', 'President', 'VP', ' 2nd VP', '3rd VP']
```

The desired output must be like this:

```
[{'title':'King'}, {'title':'President'}, {'title':'VP'}, {'title':'2nd VP'}, {'title':'3rd VP'}]
```

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using List Comprehension

```
lst = ['King', 'President', 'VP', ' 2nd VP', '3rd VP']
d_lst = [{'title': v} for v in lst]
```

```
d_lst = [{'title': 'King'}, {'title': 'President'}, {'title': 'VP'}, {'title': ' 2nd VP'}, {'title': '3rd VP'}]
```

Comment: So cool, thanks Ram for providing another way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with list comprehension

```
titles = ['King', 'President', 'VP', ' 2nd VP', '3rd VP']

print([{'title': title} for title in titles])

# output
[{'title': 'King'}, {'title': 'President'}, {'title': 'VP'}, {'title': ' 2nd VP'}, {'title': '3rd VP'}]
```

Comment: Thank you Scoot! That solves it indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?:

```
liste = ['King', 'President', 'VP', ' 2nd VP', '3rd VP']

for i in range(0, 5):
    liste[i] = {'title':liste[i]}
```

Comment: Lovely, this is another elegant way to solve it. Thanks ilou!